# Pip broke so I ran 'sudo apt remove conda* --purge', are these files essential?

Tags: apt, package-management, pip

Uodate:

> virt-manager works after enabling port forwarding.
>
> pip egg still broken, unsure how to reinstall that
>
> Rebooting is fine

List of packages that `sudo apt remove conda --purge` removed

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-dev-3.0.0.4-124af' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-prof-0.8.0-4b231:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-prof-0.5.5.3-e3935' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-dev-0.5.5.3-e3935' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-prof-1.8.0-6564b' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-dev-0.3.0-ed43d:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-prof-2.3.1-54179' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-prof-0.2.2-5d714' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'condor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-dev-1.3.2-103c2:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'globus-gram-job-manager-setup-condor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-prof-0.3.0-7a2ef' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-dev-0.8.0-4b231:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-prof-1.3.1-b1716' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-dev-0.1.1.2-d1163:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-dev-1.4.0-ef06b' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'htcondor-dbg' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-dev-1.3.0.3-e2da7:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'htcondor-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-prof-0.6.8.1-59e8e:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-dev-0.6.8.1-88111' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-prof-1.0.0.1-3c79b' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'htcondor-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-prof-0.1.1-2ad4d:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libmodule-load-conditional-perl' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'trove-conductor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-dev-1.4.0-f009f:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'ironic-conductor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-prof-1.3.2-e9d1e' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-prof-0.4.1.1-20270:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-dev-0.2.2-b7cec:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-dev-0.1.1-9d304' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-dev-1.3.1-57c65:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-dev-4.7.0-f30c0' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'globus-gram-job-manager-condor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'nova-conductor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-prof-3.0.0.4-c8eca:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-prof-0.1.1.2-4ff9f' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-dev-0.4.1.1-20270:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'globus-gram-job-manager-setup-condor-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'condor-dbg' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'condor-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'condor-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-prof-1.3.0.3-5c04f' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-dev-2.3.1-03022:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-dev-1.8.0-e932b:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-dev-1.0.0.1-3c79b' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-dev-3.0.0.4-c8eca:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-prof-1.3-69c78:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-dev-4.7.0-e8567:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-dev-1.3.0-56e07:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-prof-1.0.0.1-cfdfa:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-prof-0.3.0-ed43d:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'magnum-conductor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-prof-1.8.0-e932b:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-prof-0.8.0-e2339' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-dev-2.3.1-54179' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-prof-1.3-0fbd5' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-dev-0.6.8.1-59e8e:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-dev-1.3.0-873f1' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-prof-4.7.0-f30c0' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-dev-0.2.2-5d714' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-prof-0.1.1.2-d1163:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-prof-1.4.0-ef06b' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-dev-1.3.2-e9d1e' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'code-of-conduct-signing-assistant' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-prof-0.1.1-9d304' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-dev-0.8.0-e2339' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-prof-0.4.1.1-e1f41' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-prof-1.4.0-f009f:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-prof-1.3.1-57c65:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-dev-1.0.0.1-cfdfa:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libplack-builder-conditionals-perl' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-prof-1.3.2-103c2:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-prof-4.7.0-e8567:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-dev-1.3.0.3-5c04f' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-prof-1.3.0-56e07:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-dev-0.4.1.1-e1f41' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-dev-1.3-69c78:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-dev-0.3.0-7a2ef' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-prof-0.2.2-b7cec:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-dev-1.3.1-b1716' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-prof-0.6.8.1-88111' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-prof-1.3.0.3-e2da7:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'virtuoso-vad-conductor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'restorecond' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-dev-0.1.1-2ad4d:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-dev' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-doc' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-prof-1.3.0-873f1' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-dev-0.1.1.2-4ff9f' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-prof-3.0.0.4-124af' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'htcondor' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-dev-1.3-0fbd5' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-prof-0.5.5.3-28530:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-dev-0.5.5.3-28530:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-prof' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-prof-2.3.1-03022:i386' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'condetri' for regex 'conda*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-dev-1.8.0-6564b' for regex 'conda*'
Package 'condor' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'globus-gram-job-manager-condor' instead of 'globus-gram-job-manager-setup-condor'
Package 'globus-gram-job-manager-setup-condor-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'condor-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'condor-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'condor-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-conduit-dev-1.3.0.3-5c04f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-http-conduit-dev-2.3.1-54179'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-dev-0.5.5.3-e3935'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-dev-1.8.0-6564b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-conduit-prof-1.3.0.3-5c04f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-http-conduit-prof-2.3.1-54179'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-prof-0.5.5.3-e3935'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-prof-1.8.0-6564b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-dev' instead of 'libghc-conduit-extra-dev-1.3.0-873f1'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-prof' instead of 'libghc-conduit-extra-prof-1.3.0-873f1'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-binary-conduit-dev-1.3-0fbd5'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-binary-conduit-prof-1.3-0fbd5'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-cereal-conduit-dev-0.8.0-e2339'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-cereal-conduit-prof-0.8.0-e2339'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-dev-1.4.0-ef06b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-prof-1.4.0-ef06b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-dev' instead of 'libghc-cond-dev-0.4.1.1-e1f41'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-prof' instead of 'libghc-cond-prof-0.4.1.1-e1f41'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-dev-0.1.1-9d304'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-prof-0.1.1-9d304'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-dev-0.2.2-5d714'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-prof-0.2.2-5d714'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-csv-conduit-dev-0.6.8.1-88111'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-csv-conduit-prof-0.6.8.1-88111'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-dev-1.0.0.1-3c79b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-prof-1.0.0.1-3c79b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-html-conduit-dev-1.3.1-b1716'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-html-conduit-prof-1.3.1-b1716'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-dev' instead of 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-dev-1.3.2-e9d1e'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-prof' instead of 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-prof-1.3.2-e9d1e'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-shell-conduit-dev-4.7.0-f30c0'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-shell-conduit-prof-4.7.0-f30c0'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-dev' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-dev-0.1.1.2-4ff9f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-prof' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-prof-0.1.1.2-4ff9f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-twitter-conduit-dev-0.3.0-7a2ef'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-twitter-conduit-prof-0.3.0-7a2ef'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-dev' instead of 'libghc-wai-conduit-dev-3.0.0.4-124af'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-prof' instead of 'libghc-wai-conduit-prof-3.0.0.4-124af'
Package 'condetri' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-conduit-dev-1.3.0.3-e2da7:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-http-conduit-dev-2.3.1-03022:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-dev-0.5.5.3-28530:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-dev-1.8.0-e932b:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-conduit-prof-1.3.0.3-e2da7:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-http-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-http-conduit-prof-2.3.1-03022:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-tagstream-conduit-prof-0.5.5.3-28530:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-prof-1.8.0-e932b:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-conduit-extra-dev-1.3.0-56e07:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-conduit-extra-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-conduit-extra-prof-1.3.0-56e07:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-binary-conduit-dev-1.3-69c78:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-binary-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-binary-conduit-prof-1.3-69c78:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-cereal-conduit-dev-0.8.0-4b231:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cereal-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-cereal-conduit-prof-0.8.0-4b231:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-dev-1.4.0-f009f:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-classy-prelude-conduit-prof-1.4.0-f009f:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-cond-dev-0.4.1.1-20270:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cond-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-cond-prof-0.4.1.1-20270:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-dev-0.1.1-2ad4d:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-cryptohash-conduit-prof-0.1.1-2ad4d:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-dev-0.2.2-b7cec:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-cryptonite-conduit-prof-0.2.2-b7cec:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-csv-conduit-dev-0.6.8.1-59e8e:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-csv-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-csv-conduit-prof-0.6.8.1-59e8e:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-dev-1.0.0.1-cfdfa:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-dice-entropy-conduit-prof-1.0.0.1-cfdfa:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-html-conduit-dev-1.3.1-57c65:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-html-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-html-conduit-prof-1.3.1-57c65:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-dev-1.3.2-103c2:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-network-conduit-tls-prof-1.3.2-103c2:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-shell-conduit-dev-4.7.0-e8567:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-shell-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-shell-conduit-prof-4.7.0-e8567:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-dev-0.1.1.2-d1163:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-xml-conduit-writer-prof-0.1.1.2-d1163:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-twitter-conduit-dev-0.3.0-ed43d:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-twitter-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-twitter-conduit-prof-0.3.0-ed43d:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-wai-conduit-dev-3.0.0.4-c8eca:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-wai-conduit-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-wai-conduit-prof-3.0.0.4-c8eca:i386'
Package 'code-of-conduct-signing-assistant' is not installed, so not removed
```

Update: `sudo apt update --fix-missing` and `sudo upgrade` seemed to have fixed things. I haven't a clue, honestly. Output:

```
root@vis-1888:~# apt update --fix-missing
root@vis-1888:~# apt upgrade
[...]
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon firefox firefox-locale-en
  grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc grub-pc-bin
  grub2-common libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3 libavahi-common3:i386 libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1
  libvncclient1 nodejs openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless opera-stable
  python3-distupgrade python3-update-manager ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt update-manager-core
32 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[...]
```

Here's my pip3 output:

```
vis@vis-1888:~$ pip3 install egg --force-reinstall
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py:339: UserWarning: Unbuilt egg for Unknown [unknown version] (/home/vis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
  self.satisfied_by = pkg_resources.get_distribution(str(no_marker))
Collecting egg
Collecting chicken (from egg)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2570, in version                                                    
    return self._version                                                        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2677, in __getattr__                                                
    raise AttributeError(attr)                                                  
AttributeError: _version                                                        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:             

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 349, in run
    self._warn_about_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 475, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 98, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 41, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2575, in version
    raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self)
ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version] (/home/vis/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages))
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Turned on port forwarding through my VPN and it works. Pip still broken. Did a bunch of stuff and didn't document it, so I don't know what I should've done to fix it. I

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the packages removed were nonessential. Reboot no problem.

Reinstalling Python 2/3 fixed the pip issues. Used [deadnsake's repo](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for some and also used Python's official installs (as others have said, always take care of your security when using unofficial sources to install Python).

When compiling, I used `make altinstall` for Python3.6.7 and did regular installs for 2.7.15+ and 3.7.2. I've read there's not much reason to have >3.6 if you're not a developer so I'd keep that in mind in regards to package compatibility.

I've also installed the apt packages you generally do when installing Python, such as `python3-pip1`, `python3-pyqt5`, etc. If I already had the package I would run

`sudo apt install [package] --reinstall --fix-missing -f -y`

if it wasn't working.